# How do I launch android app from appium though it has permission denied exception

Tags: android, appium

I have a scenario to do a mobile automation with the androd app. The issue here is, I am getting `Permission` denied error when launching through `appium`.

`Appium forum` suggested that, need to add the `android: export= false` parameter in their `manifest`.

My question is, Is there any workaround to launch without amending the `manifest`.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes apps have a specific activity that allows you to enter. It routes you to the main activity. Would be best if you could consult with the developers of the app to provide the activity name.